# cron job runs in cron.daily, but not crontab file. Tried debug methods suggested already.

Tags: cron

I apologize already for asking *another* cron question. I read dozens of help articles online with still no solution. So for my curiosity, I need to find a solution.

---

**I simply want to run a command every day at 4am.** This is what I have done so far:

1. `# crontab -e`. Add this line: `00 04 * * * root ruby /home/script.rb list >> /tmp/output.log`. (script.rb just contains "puts 'hello'")
2. script.rb is owned by root and permissions are set to execute on all users.
3. I ran `rvm cron setup` to install some environment variables to the crontab file for the cron job to find my ruby executable files.
4. Added more environment variables to crontab file such as my `PATH`, `SHELL=/bin/bash` and `BASH_ENV=/root/.bashrc`.

After 4am, I check the cron logs and indeed, the script was executed. 
`Dec 14 4:00:01 admin CRON[25374]: (root) CMD (root ruby /home/script.rb list >> /tmp/output.log)` but when I check `/tmp`, no output.log file exists. When I run the command by itself, /tmp/output.log shows up and contains hello so the command works.

5. So I go back to my crontab file and change `ruby` to `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby` (output of `which ruby`) to make everything absolute paths. It runs, but still no /tmp/output.log.
6. I replace the line in crontab to: `00 04 * * * root /home/run_script` instead where `run_script` contains:
   `#!/bin/bash 
   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby /home/script.rb list >> /tmp/output.log`

   to simply try using a script file instead of one line command in crontab. It runs, but still no /tmp/output.log.
7. I go into `run_script` file and get rid of all the ruby stuff and go the simple route:
   `#!/bin/bash
   echo "hello" >> /tmp/output.log`

   It runs, but still no /tmp/output.log.

I should also note, I set `MAILTO=root` in my crontab file, but no mail delivered to root.

9. Now I did another experiment, when I take `run_script` and put it into `/etc/cron.daily`, it runs great. No problems.

Other notes: Cron is running: `ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep` outputs cron is running. There is a blank line after my command in the crontab file.

cron seems pretty tough to debug. The sys log just tells me that the cron job ran but tells nothing else. I am not getting any mail delivered so that cannot help me. Luckily /etc/cron.daily works for now, but I want to know why crontab is not working.

Any suggestions, ideas, hints at debugging?

Comment: Yeah, I followed that post. Tried everything it said, no luck.

Comment: @levibostian you must have missed something. The solution to your problem (as stated) is in that post.

Answer (score 1):

That's the wrong format for a user's crontab file. You need to remove the user specification `root'. You would have that in`/etc/crontab' but not a per-user crontab.

Comment: This is already mention in the duplicate that the OP has been directed to,